# Truncating/abbreviating strings in the middle with an ellipsis (…) (or other) separators with a fixed character limit

Tags: c#, strings, .net, user-interface, string-processing

### Problem

For some user-facing string, I want to truncate it to some given maximum length (also useful for file name/path lengths on Windows etc.). However, I want to do it a little more elaborately [than just appending `...` or `…` or so at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724896/15488899), as I want to place that character in the middle.
I.e. I want both the start *and* the end of the string be visible, if truncated.

Of course, if the string is shorter, it does not need truncation and should be ignored.

Actually, I later saw [in Java you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597550/ideal-method-to-truncate-a-string-with-ellipsis) a [great method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#abbreviate-java.lang.String-int-) `StringUtils.abbrevate` in *Apache Commons* that goes much further, where [`abbreviateMiddle`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#abbreviateMiddle-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-) may actually be, what I want to do here.

For my case, I choose to *value the last side/end more*, i.e. you may get `12…def` instead of `123…ef` if truncating `1234567890abcdef` to 6 characters. But that is an implementation detail, IMHO.

### Solution

I started with *ChatGPT* making the basics/an idea and then some tests. I iterated on that [and found out about the nice `StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder), which I first passed to ChatGPT to adjust. Later I manually needed to adjust the code, as ChatGPT really has problems with counting and such applied maths (note I did use the GPT 3.5 version).
Also the tests (and *somewhat TDD*) really had helped me to get fix the issue, with *[odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488787/how-can-i-find-whether-a-number-is-even-or-odd-using-c#27488884) maximum length numbers*, as these resulted in strings being one character too short.
The last thing I changed, implementation-wise, was to adjust it to have a configurable `separator` (aka "just" a *Resharper* refactor -> *Introduce parameter* and some test adjustments), because it was previously hardcoded to `...`. Thus, I also changed the default to `…`, which is a much nicer Unicode character for an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis).

I finished it by converting it to an extension method and documenting it, as that may be generally useful.
Obviously I tried following [clean code](https://www.planetgeek.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Clean-Code-V2.4.pdf) and write as few commends as necessary. Also, the project I am working with, has a test pattern/coding guideline, where I should put tests for a method in a subclass named after that method, so tests get more tidy (similar to [`describe`](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite#section-Suites:_%3Ccode%3Edescribe%3C/code%3E_Your_Tests) blocks in [`jasmine`](https://jasmine.github.io/)).

I also thought of using/switching to `uint` for parameters that can never be < 0. However, even [.NET's `StringBuilder`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b977a834db615edb68961dfb792aa5a9ca1219b6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs#L154-L155) just uses a "usual" `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and uses `int`. As such, using `uint` here would just require casting and the benefit is unclear, IMHO, if even .NET itself does not uses `uint` here. (Though I am open for discussion, also about the fact why Microsoft implemented it that way in `StringBuilder`.)

#### Implementation

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Common extensions for manipulating strings.
/// </summary>
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This truncates/abbreviates the string and places the separator as a user-facing indicator <i>in the middle</i> of that string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>For example "1234567890abcdef" gets truncated as "12…def" if you have a limit of 6 characters.</remarks>
    /// <param name="input">the string to truncate</param>
    /// <param name="lengthLimit">the maximum length of the resulting string</param>
    /// <param name="separator">optionally, the separator to use, by default the ellipsis …</param>
    /// <returns>The truncated string, if necessary.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">if the input parameters are invalid</exception>
    public static string TruncateInMiddle(this string input, int lengthLimit, string separator = "…")
    {
        var middleIndex = lengthLimit / 2;

        if (input.Length <= lengthLimit)
            return input;

        if (separator.Length > lengthLimit)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(separator),
                $"Separator \"{separator}\" (length: {separator.Length}) must be _NOT_ be larger than the lengthLimit {lengthLimit}."
            );

        if (middleIndex < separator.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(lengthLimit),
                $"Length limit {lengthLimit} must be larger than double of length of the separation string \"{separator}\" (length: {separator.Length})x2 for proper display."
            );

        var result = new StringBuilder(lengthLimit, lengthLimit);

        result.Append(input, 0, middleIndex - separator.Length);
        result.Append(separator);
        var remainingLength = result.Length;
        Debug.Assert(remainingLength == middleIndex, "result.Length == middleIndex");

        if (lengthLimit % 2 != 0)
            remainingLength++;

        result.Append(input, input.Length - remainingLength, remainingLength);
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

#### Tests

Using *NUnit* and *FluentAssertions*.

```csharp
[TestOf(typeof(StringExtensions))]
public class StringExtensionsTest
{
    public class TruncateInMiddle : StringExtensionsTest
    {
        [TestCase(0, 1)]
        [TestCase(1, 2)]
        [TestCase(2, 3)]
        [TestCase(3, 4)]
        [TestCase(4, 5)]
        [TestCase(1, 5)]
        public void ThrowsIfSeparatorIsTooLong(int lengthLimit, int separatorLength)
        {
            // Arrange
            var separator = TestContext.CurrentContext.Random.GetString(separatorLength);

            // Act
            var action = () => "doesNotMatter".TruncateInMiddle(lengthLimit, separator);

            // Assert
            action.Should().ThrowExactly<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>()
                .WithMessage("*(Parameter 'separator')")
                .WithMessage("*Separator * must be _NOT_ be larger than * lengthLimit*")
                .WithMessage($"*{lengthLimit}*")
                .WithMessage($"*\"{separator}\"*")
                .WithMessage($"*(length: {separatorLength}*");
        }

        [Test]
        public void ThrowsForTooSmallLengthLimits([Range(4, 5)] int lengthLimit)
        {
            // Act
            var action = () => "doesNotMatter".TruncateInMiddle(lengthLimit, "...");

            // Assert
            action.Should().ThrowExactly<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>()
                .WithMessage("*(Parameter 'lengthLimit')")
                .WithMessage("*Length limit * must be larger than double of length of the separation string*")
                .WithMessage($"*{lengthLimit}*")
                .WithMessage("*\"...\"*")
                .WithMessage("*(length: 3)x2*");
        }

        [TestCase("abcde", 4, "..", ExpectedResult = "..de")]
        [TestCase("123456789", 5, "..", ExpectedResult = "..789")]
        [TestCase("1234567890abcdef", 6, "...", ExpectedResult = "...def")]
        [TestCase("1234567890abcdef", 6, "…", ExpectedResult = "12…def")]
        public string TruncatesMinimalExamplesCorrectly(string inputString, int lengthLimit, string separator)
        {
            // Act
            var outputString = inputString.TruncateInMiddle(lengthLimit, separator);
            Debug.WriteLine(outputString);

            // Assert
            outputString.Should().HaveLength(lengthLimit)
                .And.Contain(separator);

            return outputString;
        }

        [Test]
        public void AppliesLengthLimit([Random(100, 150, 5)] int randomLength, [Random(2, 100, 5)] int lengthLimit)
        {
            // Arrange
            var inputString = TestContext.CurrentContext.Random.GetString(randomLength);
            Debug.WriteLine(inputString);

            // Act
            var outputString = inputString.TruncateInMiddle(lengthLimit);
            Debug.WriteLine(outputString);

            // Assert
            outputString.Should().HaveLength(lengthLimit)
                .And.Contain("…");
        }

        [Test]
        public void ReturnsStringsSmallerThanLimitUnchanged([Random(2, 100, 5)] int randomLength,
            [Random(100, 150, 5)] int lengthLimit)
        {
            // Arrange
            var inputString = TestContext.CurrentContext.Random.GetString(randomLength);
            Debug.WriteLine(inputString);

            // Act
            var outputString = inputString.TruncateInMiddle(lengthLimit);
            Debug.WriteLine(outputString);

            // Assert
            outputString.Should().Be(inputString);
        }
    }
}
```

.NET 6.0

Comment: Is there any particular reason why do you target .NET 6? In case of .NET 8 your fail fast checks could be more streamlined due to the [new static methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-8.0#methods) of the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` class.

Comment: @PeterCsala No, but thanks yeah. It was just because the project uses this version currently.

Comment: Updated with answers and here the new version is: https://gist.github.com/rklec/8a78ae5fb5e5bcea0dcd1920d1caa0a4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me present you an alternative version of your `TruncateInMiddle` which utilizes `ReadOnlySpan`s. The core logic can be rewritten like this

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> inputSpan = input.AsSpan();
var prefixEnd = middleIndex - separator.Length;
ReadOnlySpan<char> prefix = inputSpan[..prefixEnd];

var remainingLength = lengthLimit % 2 == 0 ? middleIndex : middleIndex + 1;
var suffixStart = input.Length - remainingLength;
ReadOnlySpan<char> suffix = inputSpan[suffixStart..]; 

return string.Concat(prefix, separator, suffix);
```

- `prefix` points to the beginning of the `input` for a given length
- `suffix` points to the end of the `input` from a calculated index
- the end result is a simple string concatenation

---

I've run a simple benchmark to measure my implementation

```
BenchmarkRunner.Run<TruncateExperiment>();
```

```
[HtmlExporter]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(BenchmarkDotNet.Engines.RunStrategy.ColdStart, launchCount: 20)]
public class TruncateExperiment
{
    List<string> inputs = new();

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            inputs.Add(string.Join("", 
                Enumerable.Repeat(0, Random.Shared.Next(100))
                    .Select(n => (char)Random.Shared.Next(127))));
        }
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public void RunBaseLine() 
    { 
        foreach(var input in inputs) 
            input.TruncateInMiddle(6); 
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunNew()
    {
        foreach(var input in inputs) 
            input.TruncateInMiddleNew(6);
    }
}
```

The results on my machine

```
| Method      | Mean     | Error    | StdDev    | Median   | Ratio | RatioSD | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
|------------ |---------:|---------:|----------:|---------:|------:|--------:|----------:|------------:|
| RunBaseLine | 8.502 us | 2.885 us | 39.154 us | 4.333 us |  1.00 |    0.00 |  11.97 KB |        1.00 |
| RunNew      | 7.384 us | 2.783 us | 37.761 us | 3.375 us |  0.80 |    0.18 |   4.31 KB |        0.36 |
```

It's a bit faster and uses less memory.

Comment: Clever idea! Though I'd say the difference is minimal and depending on where you want to use the function and how performance-critical it is, one may find the `StringBuilder` version more readable/easier to understand, possibly.

Comment: @rklec `StringBuilder` would be valid in your case if you're on .NET 4. or older. But .NET 5+ /Core, you should use Span, is more performant, and memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks! Did that and combined with [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289394/280019) and got this result: https://gist.github.com/rklec/8a78ae5fb5e5bcea0dcd1920d1caa0a4

Also changed it to use `nameof` for `WithMessage` assertions in tests to check for the parameter.

Comment: @rklec It seems good to me.

Comment: @rklec If you are fine with the end result then please consider to mark one of the posts as the answer.

Comment: @rklec you should mark this as the answer, it's more beneficial to the other readers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *Peter Csala* for providing you an example on how to convert your code into using `Span<T>`, and I think his answer covered that.
I just want to add some points on other parts of the code.

- Code does not validates `input` and `separator` against `whitespace`, `empty`, and `null` cases ( a simple `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` would cover them all).
- You should use a template message for detailed messages instead, something like :

  ```
  private const string SeparatorLengthLargerThanLengthLimitExceptionMessage = "Separator '{0}' (length: {1}) must be _NOT_ be larger than the lengthLimit {2}.";

  if (separator.Length > lengthLimit)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(separator),             
      string.Format(SeparatorLengthLargerThanLengthLimitExceptionMessage, separator, separator.Length, lengthLimit));
  ```
- `lengthLimit` is not clear enough of its purpose, maybe using a more common used naming conversions would be better such as `sliceSize`, `maxLength`, `limit` ..etc. If you got stuck on naming, you can always explore `.NET` methods with similar functionality or explore other known libraries.
- `separator` a `char` would be a better choice, and you can add a separate argument for `count` number of repeated chars like `new string('.',count)`
- `lengthLimit / 2` assumes that `lengthLimit` is always even! to better handle this you can use `(int)Math.Ceiling(lengthLimit/2d);` and then you can remove this part :

  ```
  if (lengthLimit % 2 != 0)
  remainingLength++;
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Did everything except `separator` as a char. `char separator = new string('.', 3)` does not work in the method head as it is not compiler-time-constant and also I want to use any string of any length as a separator, not only `.` and not only three times. Especially I want the UTF-8 character `…` as the default. I could only replace it with `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, but then `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is again problematic) and I have problems setting a default again. Okay the last issue could be fixed with an overload, because I cannot get `ReadOnlySpan<char>?` to work for a `separator`.

Comment: `separator = new string('.', 3)` will return a `string` not `char`. perhaps my answer lead you to some confusion ?. nethertheless, `…` is `char` and not `string`. when I mentioned `new string('.', 3)` I just wanted to show you how it was implemented in `.NET`. which would be safer and maintainable approach, and widely used as well. so if you do `char separator = '…'` in your method arguments, it would compile as intended.

Comment: `input is null` && `input.Length <= maxLength` could be replaced with `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and return `input` as early as possible. because there is nothing to do at this point.